# How to retrieve a label in a Dojo for a extra locale

Tags: dojo

How do I use take advantage of the Dojo's extraLocale functionality to labels in the secondary Language for the odd scenarios where you want to display multiple languages on the same page?

Suppose I have defined an extra locale in Dojo as the following

```
var dojoConfig = {
locale : "en",
extraLocale: [ "zh-cn", "ja-jp" ]
};
```

If I then define a class in the following way if I try to use i18n I always get a Object that already contains all the English labels for the MyClass_nls.  How do I specify one of the extra locales such as "zh-cn" so that it looks up a Chinese version of the MyClass_nls?

```
define(
    [   "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
            "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
            "dojo/text!./templates/MyClass.html",
            "dojo/i18n!./nls/MyClass_nls" ],

    function(declare, lang, _TemplatedMixin,
            _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template, i18n) {

        return declare(
                "group.test.MyClass",
                [ _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
                        Evented ],
                {
```

Something like this will work but I believe this does not need the extraLocale functionality in the dojoConfig

```
var bundle = i18nResolver.getLocalization("group/mypath", "MyClass_nls", "zh-cn");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load explicitly locale bundles by including the locale in the module ID. So, `dojo/i18n!./nls/MyClass_nls` would become `dojo/i18n!./nls/zh-cn/MyClass_nls` to explicitly load the zh-cn locale. You don’t need to use `extraLocale`, which is a legacy mechanism for preloading locales in Dojo 1.6 and earlier.